# Why am I unable to add rows to my combo box's list using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am not sure why it errors when i'm trying to add an item to the combobox's list as shown below:

[image: Error]

My code to add the code to the combo box is shown below:

1.) First I count the total rows of the worksheet

```
With Worksheets("List of Payees").ListObjects("ListofPayees").ListColumns(1).Range
Total_rows_Payees = .Find(What:="*", _
    After:=.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End With
```

2.) Adding to list of the combobox
[image: Adding to List]

The `List of Payees` worksheet and the contents of row `A` is shown below:

[image: Data Table]

It works when there is at least 2 data points in the `List of Payees` worksheet or when I clear everything except the header, but it does not work with 1 item in the worksheet. Strange.

Comment: what is .Cells(1) ?

Comment: I believe it's referring to the first cell in `ListColumn(1).Range` so it will skip the headers. I only obtained the code to count rows in a `Table` object in one of the posts here. I just copy pasted that and adjusted to my application so i'm not sure what each portion of the row counting section means I just know it works.

Comment: @MarcSantos you need a loop and `.AddItem` to add each item of the list. For a detailed tutorial or alternatives see [Excel VBA ComboBox Lists](http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html)

Comment: I'll look into it. Although I don't understand why it works when I have several rows of data. It only errors after I cleared the worksheet of all rows except the header and tried adding 1 row of data

Comment: You can find issues like this by **stepping through the code** with F8 and analyzing variables along the way.  Handy reference: [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) from Chip Pearson

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks I was stepping through the code, but when it hits the yellow line, that error in the main post appears. I was not sure why it occurred, but it was answered adequately as seen below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `.List` awaits an `Array` but if `Total_rows_Payees = 2` then the range is `Range("A2:A2").Value` which returns a single value not an array.

```
If Total_rows_Payees > 2 Then
    cbxPaidTo.List = Worksheets("List of Payees").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_Payees ).Value
ElseIf Total_rows_Payees = 2 Then
    cbxPaidTo.Clear
    cbxPaidTo.AddItem Worksheets("List of Payees").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_Payees ).Value
End If
```

Comment: Yes I believe this is the problem. However, when `Total_rows_Payees = 1` it does not error unlike when `Total_rows_Payees = 2`. I wonder why is that is it because it considers  `Range("A2:A1")` as an `Array` perhaps?

Comment: @MarcSantos yes `Range("A2:A1").Value` actually returns an array as the range has 2 rows. But `Range("A2:A2").Value` does return a single value no array because the range has only 1 row it is the same as `Range("A2").Value`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense